# Getting the right position to write in a text stream

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I'm writing a python script to find and add a name attribute to any html file that has a  tag.
So far, I have something like this:

```
lfiles = glob.glob('*.html')
chars = []

for arq in lfiles:  
    #Resets all counters for a new file
    x = 0
    fullfile = []
    insertname = ''
    insertpos = 0
    addname = False
    with open(arq , 'r') as f:
        while 1:
            char = f.read(1) #reads character by character
            if not char:
                break
            fullfile.append(char) #adds to the full stream to be saved later
            if char == '<':
                appending = True
            if appending:
                chars.append(char)
            if ''.join(chars) == '<button ':
                insertpos = x #This should get the correct position to insert the name attr
                addname = True
            if char == '>' and appending:
                appending = False
                chars = []
            if addname:
                fullfile = fullfile[:insertpos]+[' name="inputname" ']+fullfile[insertpos:]
                addname = False
            x = x+1 
        print(''.join(fullfile))
```

The script is not optimized and probably does too much unnecessary processing, but it works, kinda. Most files have something like this:

```
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                ng-click="$ctrl.showFilters()"
                ng-show="!$ctrl.filters">
          <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filters
        </button>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                ng-click="$ctrl.hideFilters()"
                ng-show="$ctrl.filters">
```

After running, the output is this:

```
        <button name="inputname"  type="button" --OK!
                class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                ng-click="$ctrl.showFilters()"
                ng-show="!$ctrl.filters">
          <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filters
        </button>
        <butto name="inputname" n type="button" --Wrong position! 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                ng-click="$ctrl.hideFilters()"
                ng-show="$ctrl.filters">
```

I'm having a hard time figuring why the position is right only sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know it, I figured the problem as I was writing the question. So, what was the catch? Well, pretty much this:

```
fullfile = fullfile[:insertpos]+[' name="inputname" ']+fullfile[insertpos:]
```

This means that the fullfile's length is now 1 longer. So, instead of 10, it's 11. I wasn't setting an offset, so, every time I added the name, I would be off by +1. If it ran 5 times, i'd end up with `<b name="inputname" utton ...>` Here's the fix:

```
if addname:
    fullfile = fullfile[:insertpos]+[' name="inputname" ']+fullfile[insertpos:]
    addname = False
    x = x + 1 #The magic fix!
```

Now, my actual use case had `[' name="',insertname,'" ']`. This means that the offset is now 3, because that array is made of 3 elements, so the length is increasing by 3